# my python code corrupts '*' into '(' when pushed to a Stack class

Tags: python, stack, corruption, postfix-notation

If I push a character to the Stack and peek at it, it gives me different characters even when no interaction was made after the push.

The relevant class and functions look like this:

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []
        self.top = -1
        self.max = 10

    def isFull(self):
        if self.top == (self.max-1):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def isEmpty(self):
        if self.top == -1:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def push(self, input):
        if self.isFull():
            print(f"Push({input}) : Stack is full")
        else:
            self.top += 1
            self.data.append(input)

    def pop(self):
        if self.isEmpty():
            print("Pop : Stack is empty")
        else:
            temp = self.data[self.top]
            self.top -= 1
            return temp

    def peek(self):
        if self.isEmpty():
            print("Peek : Stack is empty")
        else:
            return self.data[self.top]
        
    def printStack(self):
        if self.isEmpty():
            print("Print : Stack is empty")
        else:
            print("Stack : ", end="")
            for i in range(0,self.top+1):
                print(self.data[i], end=" ")
            print()

def stringToList(input):
    input = input.replace(' ', '')
    result = []
    temp = ''
    i = 0
    while i < len(input):
        char = input[i]
        if char.isdigit() or char == '.':
            temp += str(char)
        else:
            if temp != "":
                result.append(float(temp))
                temp = ''
            if char == '*' and i + 1 < len(input) and input[i + 1] == '*' :
                result.append('**')
                i += 1
            else:
                result.append(char)
        i += 1
    if temp != "":
        result.append(float(temp))
    return result

def infixToPostfix(input):
    stack = Stack()
    result = []
    for i in input:
        print(f"i = '{i}'")
        if type(i) == float:
            result.append(i)
        elif i == '(':
            stack.push(i)
        elif i == ')':
            while stack.isEmpty() == False and stack.peek() != '(':
                result.append(stack.pop())
            stack.pop()
        else:
            while stack.isEmpty() == False and stack.peek() != '(' and priority(i) <= priority(stack.peek()):   
                result.append(stack.pop())
            stack.push(i)

            print(f"stack.peek() = '{stack.peek()}'")

        print(f"result = {result}")
        stack.printStack()
        print()


    while stack.isEmpty() == False:
        result.append(stack.pop())
    return result

def priority(char):
    if char == '+' or char == '-':
        return 1
    elif char == '*' or char == '/':
        return 2
    elif char == '**':
        return 3
    else:
        return -1
```

the input itself is given through the following code:

```
input = input("expression : ")
postfix = infixToPostfix(stringToList(input))
print(f"postfix : {postfix}")
```

I triple-checked that the other code( including stringToList() ) works correctly.

when given `(10+2*1.5)*3` as input, the code outputs the following:

```
i = '('
result = []
Stack : (

i = '10.0'
result = [10.0]
Stack : (

i = '+'
stack.peek() = '+'
result = [10.0]
Stack : ( +

i = '2.0'
result = [10.0, 2.0]
Stack : ( +

i = '*'
stack.peek() = '*'
result = [10.0, 2.0]
Stack : ( + *

i = '1.5'
result = [10.0, 2.0, 1.5]
Stack : ( + *

i = ')'
result = [10.0, 2.0, 1.5, '*', '+']       
Print : Stack is empty

i = '*'
stack.peek() = '('
result = [10.0, 2.0, 1.5, '*', '+']       
Stack : (

i = '3.0'
result = [10.0, 2.0, 1.5, '*', '+', 3.0]  
Stack : (

postfix : [10.0, 2.0, 1.5, '*', '+', 3.0, '(']
```

As you can see from the 8th iteration, the '*' became a '(' for no specific reason.
Expected output was :

```
i = '3.0'
result = [10.0, 2.0, 1.5, '*', '+', 3.0]  
Stack : *
```

thus making the postfix : `[10.0, 2.0, 1.5, '*', '+', 3.0, '*']`
I have moving the print(i) right above the printStack() method, but I am getting the same outputs.
I have tried all the python interpreters that I could get my hand to, but always got the same result, so i don't think it is a local env problem.

Comment: To help you with this problem, we need to run the code ourselves.  But we can't do that, because you did not show the `stringToList()` function.

Comment: @JohnGordon Sorry for the inconvenience. I added the `stringToList()` function's code.

Comment: I'm getting an error that there is no such function `self.isFull()`

Comment: @JohnGordon My bad. I added the class methods, and merged the code to a single code block for better readability.

Comment: When you pop from the stack, you aren't removing from the end of `self.data`. Therefore `self.data` retains elements at positions beyond `self.top`. That means a pop followed by a push won't work: your push method calls `self.data.append(input)`, but this adds the data at the end of the list, not at the position pointed to by `self.top`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `pop()` decrements `self.top`, but it doesn't remove the popped element from the end of `self.data`.

So `self.data` still has elements at indices greater than `self.top`.

The specific problem comes when a push follows a pop. The `push()` method calls `self.data.append(input)`, and this adds the data at the end of `self.data`, not at the position pointed to by `self.top`.

The fix is to remove the popped item from `self.data`, which you could do using the `.pop()` method of a list:

```
    def pop(self):
        if self.isEmpty():
            print("Pop : Stack is empty")
        else:
            self.top -= 1
            return self.data.pop()
```

With that change, your test input `(10+2*1.5)*3` gives the result you expect:

```
i = '3.0'
result = [10.0, 2.0, 1.5, '*', '+', 3.0]
Stack : * 

postfix : [10.0, 2.0, 1.5, '*', '+', 3.0, '*']
```

You could further improve the code by removing the use of `self.top`. With the fix here, you no longer need it, because `len(self.data)` now tells you how many items are on the stack, and the top element (assuming the stack isn't empty) is `self.data[-1]`.